# can htmlunitdriver supports downloading of files from the browser?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, htmlunit-driver

I have a code, where it downloads files from the browser (chrome or firefox), but when used headless browsers like htmlunitdriver or phantomjs, they are executing complete code but skipping downloading of files from the browser.

So would like to know will this downloading functionality is supported by htmlunitdriver and phantomjs?

Comment: Can you provide the following information: 1. What is your objective? 2. What are trying to achieve? 3. What have you tried still now? Show code. 4. Where are you struck? 5. Provide complete HTML DOM. 6. Provide snapshot of the Webpage.

Comment: Please provide the code you have tried and any error messages. Also provide a link to the page or the relevant HTML.